# Exporting model as USDZ

Tags: saving

The 3.5 release notes say exporting a model as USDZ is supported. How do I do this? The export menu does not contain usdz as an option.

The source code (linked to on the release page) says something about passing a usdc to UsdUtilsCreateNewUsdzPackage. How do you do this?

Comment: See the Note below [this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/import_export/usd.html#exporting-to-usd-files) section in the Blender manual.

Answer (score 2):

I have run across an easy-to-miss blue box in the Blender manual that says if you just type the `z` to the end of the file name as you do a `.usd*` export, it will save properly as such.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/import_export/usd.html

Comment: It is incredible but it works!!!  On a Mac I could double click on the model and it opens in Xcode 15 (beta)

Comment: This does not seem to work in Blender 4.0.  Is there some other required library that needs to be updated?  When I attempt to write .usdz I get this error: "USD Export: unable to find suitable USD plugin to write FILE_NAME.usdz"